# how can I know the number of elements in a filter ( | filter: foo)

Tags: angularjs

I want to perform a validation, that if there are no elements when making a filter, hide a div otherwise it will be displayed. This is my code:

```
<!-- show/hide this div depends if exist coincidence on the filter -->
<p class="text-center txt_color_azul_oscuro tip_fuen_roboto_l txt_sm">elements:</p>


<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" ng-repeat="item in faqs" ng-show="([item] | filter: search).length ">
.
.
.
</div>

<input class="field" type="text" type="text" ng-model="search" required>
```

Comment: You are conditioning the presentation (`ng-show`) to the existence of a value in `...length`, but not to the fact that the length is > 0. So simply add `> 0` after `...length`.

Comment: excuse me.. I dont understand you.. can you explain again please?

Comment: I'll put the explanation in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ng-show` to condition the presentation of the `div`. Now, `ng-show` expects a condition that evaluates to `true` or `false` (if `true`, show). When you leave as argument only a value (in your case), AngularJS treats it as: *if the object exists then TRUE otherwise FALSE*. Since the length of the array does exist (i.e. **0**), the evaluation results in **TRUE**.

In order to get what you want, you need the record:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" 
     ng-repeat="item in faqs" 
     ng-show="([item] | filter: search).length ">
```

to become:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" 
     ng-repeat="item in faqs" 
     ng-show="([item] | filter: search).length > 0 ">
```

How this clarifies things and also solves your problem.